# How to write a paper about marketing for publishing in ISI Journals?

Tags: publications, writing, paper-submission

I have read many ISI papers, and now I want to publish my own paper, but the subject I want to write is about marketing and brand development, which lots of people are writing in this topic. Is it possible if I don't do any mathematical or analytic researches and just write my paper based on other papers and my own knowledge and by mentioning the sources and books that I wrote my paper?
My main question is, can I just write descriptive words and mention some issue in just words, and I don't do any math or numeral calculations?
And what ISI Journal do you suggest me to send it, which will easily accept it, and has a good Impact Factor, and doesn't cost me too much?

Comment: _which will easily accept it, and has a good Impact Factor_ I think you are asking too much.

Comment: yes i ask too much, and you could answer short, which you have already done

Comment: I would really appreciate your kind attention to my questions, please give me a comprehensive reply

Comment: As far as I know, it's **not easy** to let good IF journals accept papers. That's why I said that.

Comment: aha, lol, i misunderstood. Ok just advise an easy journal with lower IF, like 1 to 2.

Comment: So your question is really: How can I publish in a highly-regarded journal without doing the hard work of research like everyone else has to do?

Comment: It seems like you're going about this completely backwards.  First you do the work (you know: research), then you write about it, and then you publish it where it fits.

Comment: For those of us in other fields, what is ISI?

Answer (score 3):

Writing for an IF journal should follow standard good practises. First you need to have a well defined question/hypothesis for the work. You need to provide a solid and up to date background for the work (Introduction providing an overview of all relevant literature, i.e. earlier work). You need to successfully show significant (new) results and conclusions. Then you need to write the paper well, which means no spelling and hopefully no grammatical errors, clear and concise language, good structure. Finally you should adhere to any instructions for authors regarding how the journal requests papers to adhere.

So this is actually not so difficult in theory. To what extent this will be easy for you depends on your experience. Based on your question, it sounds as if you are thinking more about a literature review with some own thinking on the topic, avoiding new data and data analysis. This does not sound like the easiest way to gain acceptance. Likewise, knowing your field also involves understanding what journals accept what sort of papers. You seem to be at an disadvantage also here. The best advice is therefore to try to connect to someone who knows the field better and ask for assistance in, for example discussing the problem, and possibly helping with the strategic decisions regarding format of the paper and where to send it. One has to know the details of your work to provide such advice and that is clearly beyond the scope of this site.

Finally, as already stated by scaaahu, "easy accept" is not a concept known to the majority of us when it comes to scientific publishing.

Comment: What is an "IF journal"?